# codeigniter won't add a simple view

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to add a view just a simple contact page, I already have other views.

Here's what I've done so far:

added 'contact' in my routes file here

```
$route['^(?!/|site|ajax|gallery|contact).*'] = "site/view/$1";
```

added contact.php to my application/views folder

added contact() to my site controller (whole controller here http://pastebin.com/CCjjrV8R)

```
    function contact() {
    $this->load->model('Site_model');
    $this->load->view('contact');
}
```

When I visit the correct url for the view (domain.com/contact), I get a page with partial content and "404" in the 
Can anyone see a problem? This is very puzzling.

Comment: Can you show us more of your controller?

Comment: @ThomasEdwards link added to post #1

Comment: heres the html output of the page in full,  http://pastebin.com/bdeYs6QS

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think you need the `view` part of the URL in the route?

Comment: fixed it now! $route['^(?!c).*'] = "site/$0";

this line caused it, see the 'c' changed that to a d and sorted.